# Is it possible to route all external requests through one elastic IP in AWS VPC Network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have several EC2 instances which need to have a white listed IP address to talk with an external service. Is it possible to have these all route through the same Elastic IP when they make external calls using strictly AWS features (not another nginx reverse proxy server)?

I need them to all go through 1 IP so that I can support auto scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 12/18/2015:**
There is now a managed NAT solution that can be used to solve this problem.
 See:  https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/introducing-amazon-vpc-nat-gateway-a-managed-nat-service/

**Original Answer:**
You basically need a NAT host and you need to point all traffic that has a destination outside of the VPC to the NAT instance.
Give the NAT instance the whitelisted ip.
Here are the docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html

Comment: When you say "point all traffic" do you mean by using route tables or by editing my etc/hosts file or some other method?

Comment: route table. follow the docx :)

Comment: I see now. My goal was to not have that extra server so I was overlooking things. Looks like a proxy server is unavoidable.

Comment: yeah. AWS VPC does not have a good solution for nat-ing. you could in theory proxy all the traffic through one service server but the setup is more complicated and you need to track what the server is and give it snowflake status.